Can $3000 of already existing capital losses be used in next year instead of current year?
Let's say for someone who has modest ordinary income this year, but next year expects significantly more income - is it possible to defer usage of capital loss to the next year? Or, is this person required to use all $3000 of capital loss in current year if income in current year was $3000 or more?

You cannot defer it. But, if your total taxable income after the deduction ends up being negative - you get a NOL (net operating loss) which you can carry forward to the next year.
If you are asking about deferring to the next year to get a higher marginal tax benefit then no, you cannot do that.
